# Sum up values after retrieving from database using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am fetching some information from mysql database and I am displaying it using the following script(I am using Codeigniter)

```
 <?php if(count($records) > 0) { ?>

   <?php $i = $this->uri->segment(3) + 0; foreach ($records as $row){ $i++; ?>
<?php echo $row['amount']; ?>    <br>

<?php  } ?>

<?php } else { echo "No Record Found";} ?>
```

The out put I get is like following

```
10,000
20,000.34
15,250.50
```

Now what I am trying to do is sum up all the values that are in `$row['amount'];` and put the value of the summation in `$sum_value` so that when I echo $sum_value I get the following value

```
45,250.84
```

Would you please kindly show me how to do it.

I know I could have done the summation things using mysql, but I want to learn how to do this way.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iteratively add to your sum with each loop through the foreach:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ( $records as $row ) {
  $sum += str_replace(",", "", $row['amount']);
}

echo number_format( $sum, 2 );
```

Comment: Wont work. His numbers are strings which php will consider as 10, 20 and 15

Comment: @d_inevitable Good point. Removing the commas permits the proper cast.

Comment: @black_belt Geniuses work in the Apple Store. I'm just a developer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
<?
if(count($records) > 0) {
   $i = $this->uri->segment(3) + 0; 
   $sum_value = 0;
   foreach ($records as $row){ 

      $i++; // Don't know what you use $i for, get rid of it if unnecessary

      // Add value to the sum
      $sum_value += (float)str_replace(",", "", $row["amount"]); 

      // Print the current value
      echo $row['amount'] + "<br/>";

   }

   echo $sum_value;  // Print the total sum after the loop

} else { 
   echo "No Record Found";
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert it into proper numbers:

```
$nums = array_map(function(&$row) {
   return (float) str_replace(',', '',$row['amount']);
}, $records);
```

Then you can use `array_sum`:

```
echo number_format(array_sum($nums), 2);
```